# function name and class name are same. How the compiler is working? How or Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If class is called, why constructor is not print the statement. If class is not called then why that print statement is worked? Both time we calling the outer but one time only print function is working?

example.py

```
class outer:
    print("print")
    def __init__(self, h):
        print("Constructor ",h)

def outer(msg):
    print(msg)

outer("hello")
outer("hello")
```

output :

```
print
hello
hello
```

Comment: `def outer` overwrites `class outer` within the scope you've defined here. `"print"` is printed because it's called in the class definition of `class outer` but *not* in the constructor. You've called the *function* outer (twice), and you've never instantiated the *class* `outer` because it no longer exists.

Comment: That `print("print")` is executed upon module import.

Comment: Try `print(type(outer))`

Answer (score 2):

There are two different scopes here - a similar piece of code using module scope instead of class scope:

```
print("initialization print")

def outer(msg):
    print("message", msg)

def outer(msg):
    print("message #2", msg)

outer("hello")
outer("hello")
```

will produce:

```
initialization print
message 2 hello
message 2 hello
```

The key thing to learn is that everything indented under `class` executes during the **class'** definition time, while everything indented under `def __init__(self)` happens at the **instance's** definition time:

```
class Example:
    print("Defining what it means to be an Example")
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("Creating an instance of Example with the name ", name)

print("Example class created - no instances yet")
Example("Joe")
```

will produce:

```
Defining what it means to be an Example
Example class created - no instances yet
Creating an instance of Example with the name Joe
```

The second point is that you are overwriting the *binding* of the class `outer` after it is created with function.  If we had anonymous classes and functions in Python you could look at them as assignments:

```
x = 1
x = 2
```

is just like:

```
outer = class:
    print("Creating class outer")
    # ... etc. ...

outer = def(msg):
    # you get the idea
```

Answer (score 1):

`print("print")` is executed when the class is defined, not when it is initialized.
`def outer(msg): ...` then overrides the class definition. Therefore `__init__` is never called.

From the documentation:

> In practice, the statements inside a class definition will usually be function definitions, but other statements are allowed, and sometimes useful [...]

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax

Answer (score 0):

`def outer` overwrites `class outer` within the scope you've defined here. `"print"` is printed because it's called in the class definition of `class outer` but *not* in the constructor. You've called the *function* outer (twice), and you've never instantiated the *class* `outer` because it no longer exists.

If you run this in console, it's apparent. Before we redefine `outer` as a function, the `print` statement within the class definition is executed:

[image]